# Zend Framework - sometimes strange errors in few environments

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have project written in Zend Framework and it works fine most of environments.

For example it works good in Windows 7 and Windows XP with popular browsers such as IE, Firefox, Opera and Google Chrome.

In my computer it also works on Ubuntu, but in my friend's computer on ubuntu sometimes it doesn't.

For example: it worked fine yesterday morning, but later it didn't load and there was this error:

```
Zend_Session::start() - /var/www/try/library/Zend/Loader.php(Line:146): 
Error #2  Zend_Loader::include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Req.php' for 
inclusion (include_path='.:/var/www/try/application/../library:/var/www/try 
/application/../lib:/var/www/try/application/models/:/var/www/try
/application/models/generated/:/var/www/try/application/controllers/:/var
/www/try/application/forms/:.:/usr/share/php') Array
```

Sometimes even css isn't loaded...

It's like $this->configuration['baseUrl'] suddenly don't work.

What it could be?

Restarting the browser usually helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is that, there was some a problem with session, and the application looked for files from another application, which was used before (application was in the same server).

I found the answer accidently, when I was doing something in that other application and I found there the Req.php file...

Answer (score 1):

**What happened?**

An include failed when the application tried to load 'Req.php'
This appears to be that the classes are not autoloading correctly.

**What to check?**

- Check you have the required libraries installed correctly, and matching the folders on your include path. i.e. run a search in your project for Req.php, check this actually exists.
- Check where your include path is set - try wrapping the following line in a realpath(), the environment may not like the '../library' in the path.

/var/www/try/application/../library

Comment: but the problem is, that I don't have any classes named Req and I don't have the file Req.php, I have no idea, why it's looking for such a file...

Comment: Do you have a file or class called something like `Req` and you have misspelled it?